# Why does adjusting the kernel environment for matplotlib graphs sometimes have color, and when I run it on another kernel it does not?

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I can run a block of code, and the graph will display alternating colors, and I can run the same block of code on a different kernel environment and there will be no colors. Attached are the images.

**Kernel 1:**
[image]
https://imgur.com/a/WDuqr60

**Kernel 2:**
[image]
https://imgur.com/a/y2GtYJb

Comment: This is not a [mcve]. You plot a graph after having run 11 or even 123 other cells in your notebook and noone knows what you have defined in those previous cells which could potentially cause the observed difference.

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/G1OE42f

https://imgur.com/a/yufuPEi

Here I ran the same cell, but just switched the kernel environment from conda env:dsi to default.

Comment: What exactly is `env:dsi`? Which one of the images is created with which environment? Which packages are different between the two environments? What is in the prior 10 cells?

Comment: Could it because it's defferent matplotlibrc in different envs?

Comment: I strongly doubt it's the matplotlibrc file alone, because there is no way to force barplot colors from within rcParams. I rather suspect some additional package being loaded, but with the information at hand, it's close to impossible to find out.

Comment: it must be something with the env:dsi, because all of the cells ran before are the same. it's just seaborn and matplotlib.pyplot. thank you all!